# Any good reason to slice a LUN and create several VGs instead of create just one VG?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm

I'm the new administrator for a Linux RHEL box which uses a fibre channel 1-TB LUN disk.

I find amazing the following: this LUN has been sliced by means of GNU parted(1), then each slice is turned into a disk device. Several volume groups have been created using these new disk devices, and they contain just a logical volume occupying the entire slice.

Instead, I would have created a volume group using the whole 1-TB LUN and created several logical volumes.

Is there any reason to have sliced the LUN instead of use LVM as a first step?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone has anticipated a need to grow those volume groups separately from each other by adding later new phsyical devices (disks/partitions). By partitioning it is possible to consume single disk space for more than one volume group.